# Req.file is undefined nodejs multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am getting this unexpected error nodejs(Express).
**Whenever I console req.file or req.files, undefined is consoled**

#### Error screenshot

[image: Undefined error]

#### Postman Config

[image: Post man configuration]

## code

Three files are as follow:

### userController.js

> for signup

```js
const express = require("express");
const profilePictureConfig = require("../multer/profilePictureConfig");
const userModel = require("../models/userModel");
const tokenRequired = require("../middleware/tokenRequired");
const genHash = require("../helper/genHash");
router = express.Router();

router
  .post("/signup", profilePictureConfig, async (req, res, next) => {
    let profile_picture = req.file?.path ? `\\${req.file.path}` : null;
    console.log("req file here");
    console.log(req.file); // Prints undefined
    console.log(req.files); // Prints undefined
    try {
      const hash = await genHash(req.body.password);
      let newUser = new userModel({
        ...req.body,
        password: hash,
        is_admin: false,
        profile_picture,
      });
      await newUser.save();
      res.status(200).send(newUser);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.errors);
      next(e);
    }
  })
```

### profilePictureConfig

> handles all multer configuration

```
const multer = require("multer");

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(null, "./public/pp");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(null, Date.now() + " -- " + file.originalname);
  },
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).single("profile_picture");
```

### app.js

> Parent to all files

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const tokenHandler = require("./middleware/tokenHandler");
const userController = require("./controller/userController");

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use(tokenHandler);
app.use("/user", userController);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("404! Not Found");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send({ error: err.message });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks ok. Can you check do you have the subfolder `pp` in `public` folder? Maybe you did not create that folder, so `Multer` can not store file there.